# Problemas com algoritmo extenso

Tags: c++, algoritmo, c++11

Não sei o que fazer, acho que cometi algum erro que não conheço.

No meu programa o usuário deve pensar em um número, e o computador deve tentar adivinhar qual é o número que o usuário pensou. O computador pode pedir para o usuário por algumas vezes se o número que ele pensou é maior, menor ou igual ao número que o usuário pensou.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string resp;
int res;
int contr;

int resposta(int valor){
    cout<<"O número que você digitou é "<<valor<<endl;
}

int metade(int meta){
    if(contr == 50){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + contr/2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - contr/2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 75 || contr == 25){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 12;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 12;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr ==  87|| contr == 63 ){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 6;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 6;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 13 || contr == 37 ){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 6;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 6;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 93 || contr == 81){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 69 || contr == 57){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 7  || contr == 19){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(contr == 31 || contr == 43){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 3;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 96 || crtl == 90){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 72 || crtl == 66){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 78 || crtl == 84){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 60 || crtl == 54){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 10 || crtl == 4){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 22 || crtl == 16){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 28 || crtl == 34){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }else if(crtl == 40 || crtl == 46){
        if(meta == 1){
            contr = contr + 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else if(meta == 2){
            contr = contr - 2;
            descobridor(contr);
        }else{
            cout<<"Cheiro de Erro... interno"<<endl;
        }
    }

}

int descobridor(int crtl){
    if(crtl == 75 || crtl == 25){ //1 parte
        cout<<"Seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 87 || crtl == 63 ){ //2 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 13 || crtl == 37 ){ //2 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 93 || crtl == 81){ //3 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 69 || crtl == 57){ //3 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 7 || crtl == 19){ //3parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 31 || crtl == 43){ //3 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 96 || crtl == 90){ //4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 72 || crtl == 66){ //4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);]
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 78 || crtl == 84){ //4parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 60 || crtl == 54){ //4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 10 || crtl == 4){//4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 22 || crtl == 16){ // 4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 28 || crtl == 34){//4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }else if(crtl == 40 || crtl == 46){//4 parte
        cout<<"O seu número é maior ou igual a "<<contr<<"?"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        res = compUni(resp,contr);
        compres();
    }/*else if(crtl == ) codigo esta por terminar */

}

int compUni(string digitado, int control){
    int valor;
    if(digitado == "Sim"){
        valor = 1;
        return valor;
    }else if(digitado == "Nao"){
        valor = 2;
        return valor;
    }else if(digitado == "Igual"){
        valor = 3;
        return valor;
    }else{
        cerr<<"Não sou burro, só pra constar viu, mas confesso que não entendi você";
        valor = 4;
        return valor;
    }
}

int compres(){
    int val;
    switch(res){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Então é maior que "<<contr<<endl;
            val = 1;
            metade(val);
        case 2:
            cout<<"Então é menor que "<<contr<<endl;
            val = 2;
            metade(val);
        case 3:
            resposta(contr);
        case 4:
            cout<<"Digite novamente"<<endl;
            cin>>resp;
            ::res = compUni(resp,contr);
            compres();
        default:
            cout<<"To bugadão tio, malz ae"<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){ //versão 2.0 pq tava muito extenso //esse ficou maior ainda pelo menos eu evito varios if atras do outro e dentro do outro sla mo bagunça
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    cout<<"Este programa funciona da seguinte maneira... \n"
        <<"Pense num número de 1 a 100 que eu vou usar minhas habilidades... \n"
        <<"Agora quero que responda usando Sim , Nao e Igual... \n Boa Sorte!! \n"
        <<"Tipo assim, Sim quando for maior, Nao quando for menor, e igual... quando for igual né poxa! \n"
        <<"Seu número é maior ou igual a 50?"
        <<endl;
    cin>>resp;
    contr = 50;
    ::res = compUni(resp,contr);
    compres();
    resposta(contr);
    descobridor(contr);
}
```

Comment: Qual mensagem de erro? Olhando por cima, seu codigo parece estar muito "amador" pra nao dizer coisa pior, de uma refatorada nele, impossivel voce precisar de todos esses ifs pra tratar apenas com numeros!

Comment: Comecei com c++ faz pouco tempo

Comment: Não tenho ideia de como fazer o programa achar seu número pensado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, ao invés de ficar usando esse monte de `if`s gambiarrados e horrorosos, use matemática. Imagina se você quisesse fazer esse programa para números de 1 a 1.000.000.000? Ficaria monstruoso!

Segundo, não copie e cole código. **Sempre que você copia e cola código, um bebê foca do Alasca engole óleo vazado no mar e morre.** Portanto, nunca copie e cole código!

Terceiro, seu código tem erros de compilação. Às vezes você usa `contr` e às vezes `ctrl`. Você também colocou as funções fora da ordem correta. Tem um monte de erros, nem me dei ao trabalho de ver tudo.

Refiz o seu programa inteiro. Ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

enum Resposta {
    Maior, Menor, Igual
};

void maiusculas(string &s) {
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper));
}

Resposta perguntar(int valor) {
    while (1) {
        cout << "Seu número é 'Maior', 'Menor' ou 'Igual' a " << valor << "?" << endl;
        string resp;
        cin >> resp;
        maiusculas(resp);
        if (resp == "MAIOR") return Maior;
        if (resp == "MENOR") return Menor;
        if (resp == "IGUAL") return Igual;
        cout << "Não sou burro, só pra constar viu, mas confesso que não entendi você." << endl;
    }
}

void descobridor(int min, int max) {
    while (1) {
        if (max < min) {
            cout << "Sabe o que você é?" << endl
                 << "UM BAITA DE UM MENTIROSO." << endl
                 << "BABACA!" << endl
                 << "Não quero mais brincar com você..." << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (max == min) {
            cout << "O número que você pensou é " << max << "." << endl;
            return;
        }
        int meio = (max + min) / 2;
        Resposta resp = perguntar(meio);
        if (resp == Menor) {
            max = meio - 1;
        } else if (resp == Maior) {
            min = meio + 1;
        } else if (resp == Igual) {
            min = max = meio;
        } else {
            cout << "Tô bugadão tio, malz aê..." << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    cout << "Este programa funciona da seguinte maneira..." << endl
         << "Pense num número de " << min << " a " << max << " que eu vou usar minhas habilidades..." << endl
         << "Agora quero que responda usando 'Maior', 'Menor' e 'Igual'..."
         << "Boa Sorte!" << endl;
    descobridor(min, max);
}
```

A parte de converter a string para maiúscula, eu peguei [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418407/540552).

Ah, se você quiser mudar ele para um número de 1 a 1.000.000, só basta mudar o `max` do `main` e não precisa reescrever tudo.

Comment: Nunca usei enum, na verdade não cheguei nessa parte do livro, mesmo assim obrigado, vou evitar comparações gambiarradas e usar mais a lógica

Answer (score -1):

Não precisa comparar cada número, algo assim ja basta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int numero, acertou = 0;
    int aleatorio = rand() % 100 + 1;

    while(!acertou) {

        printf("\nDigite um numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);

        if(numero > aleatorio) {
            printf("E maior.\n");
        } else if(numero < aleatorio) {
            printf("E menor.\n");
        } else {
            printf("\nVoce acertou, %d era o numero", aleatorio);
            acertou = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, não é o usuário que tem que adivinhar qual o número que o computador pensou, e sim o computador adivinhar o número que o usuário pensou.

Comment: É essa a ideia, um dos algoritmos que pensei seria esse... mas ai deu ruim